# Recursively count children nodes in binary tree

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree, nodes

My coding exercise is given the reference to the node count its children.
I decided to use recursion, and I was wondering is this a elegant way to do this:

Let's assume there is class Node which represents every node in the tree:

```
public Node {
  int data:
  Node left;
  Node right;
}


int countChildren(Node head) {
    if(head==null) return 0;
    return countChildren(head.left)+countChildren(head.right)+ 
            ((head.left==null)?0:1) + ((head.right==null)?0:1);
}
```

Comment: What should we suggest?

Comment: Did you try it? Did it give you the correct number of children for various trees?

Comment: i suggest you make it java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Node {
  int data:
  Node left;
  Node right;
}


int countChildren(Node head) {
    if(head==null) return 0;
    return ((head.left == null) ? 0 : countChildren(head.left) + 1) + ((head.right == null) ? 0 : countChildren(head.right) + 1);
}
```

This is my suggestion.